# Magento Import - Fatal error: Call to a member function prepareAttributesForSave() on a non-object in Product.php

Tags: magento, fatal-error

When attempting to import a csv product file into magento it keeps staying at "please wait". After using firebug I found I was getting this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepareAttributesForSave() on a non-object in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php on line 1259

Here's line 1259 in product.php:

```
$rowData      = $this->_productTypeModels[$productType]->prepareAttributesForSave($rowData);
        $product      = Mage::getModel('importexport/import_proxy_product', $rowData);
```

I am a complete newbie to PHP and am not sure how to fix this. I tried searching google, but didn't find anything related to this specific function.

Comment: After going through my system log I found this: 2013-06-30T06:17:46+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: bundle  in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php on line 1259